# MySQL subtract from Count Null

Tags: mysql, sql, subtraction, ifnull

I have a movie rental Database where I have to calculate how many copies of a given movie I have available.
I Have 3 tables:

a) "Movies"
-Id_Movie PK,
-Name,
-Copies_num

b) "Client"
-Id_Client PK,
-Client_Name

c)"rentals"
Movie_Id PK FK,
Client_ID PK FK,
Rental_Date,
Movie_return_date

So I thought, if the movie_return_date is null that means 1 copy is rented, so that means i have
(Copies_num - COUNT(NULLS of movie return date) but i cant quite figure how to do such SELECT query

`SELECT Distinct M.Title, M.Copies_num as 'max_num',M.Copies_num - COUNT(IFNULL(R.Movie_return_date , NULL)) as avalible FROM rentals R LEFT JOIN Movies M ON M.Id_Movie = R.Movie_ID GROUP BY M.Copies_num, M.Title;`

This kinda works but it subtracks from the wrong movie, the one that does not have any nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT Distinct M.Title, M.Copies_num as 'max_num', M.copies_num- 
COUNT(rental_date) AS available
FROM rental R right JOIN Movies M ON M.Id_Movie = R.Movie_ID 
WHERE movie_return_date is null
GROUP BY M.Copies_num, M.Title;
```